# How to increase width of column of table in word file by JAVA

Tags: java, apache-poi, column-width

I working on a small project where I am creating word file by Java and enter some detail in this word file.
I am able to create word file and also able to enter data into it. I also write a table into word file and enter some details.

**Now what I want, I want to increase width of specific column.**

Is there any way to do this? I am using Apache POI drivers for creating word file and writing data into it.

I am using below code:

```
XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
try{
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
new File("d:\\createparagraph.docx"));

 XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
     XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
     XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
     tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("CLientID");   
     tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText(txtCID.getText());
  //create second row
    XWPFTableRow tableRow2 = table.createRow();
    tableRow2.getCell(0).setText("AccountID");
    tableRow2.getCell(1).setText(txtAID.getText());
document.write(out);
out.close();
 }
```

This code working fine and generate normal table but I want to increase width of  specific column (Column 2).

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I see, the column width settings are not implemented (as of POI version 3.15 final) in `XWPFTable`. So we must use the underlying low level objects.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTableColumnWidth {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1, 2);

  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  table.setWidth(5*1440); //should be 5 inches width

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 2 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column = 2 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  //other columns (only one in this case) = 3 inches width
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 2; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3*1440));
  }

  //set width for first column = 2 inches
  CTTblWidth tblWidth = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
  tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  //STTblWidth.DXA is used to specify width in twentieths of a point.
  tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);

  //set width for second column = 3 inches
  tblWidth = table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
  tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3*1440));
  tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);

  XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
  tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("CLientID");   
  tableRowOne.getCell(1).setText("CID001");
  //create second row
  XWPFTableRow tableRow2 = table.createRow();
  tableRow2.getCell(0).setText("AccountID");
  tableRow2.getCell(1).setText("ACCID001");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableColumnWidth.docx"));
  document.close();

 }
}
```

The code is commented to describe what it does. Especially mentioned should be the special measurement unit [Twip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip) (twentieth of a point).

Comment: Understand that table widths and cell widths in Word are somewhat strange. That is, they are only suggested widths. Word can change them on display as it deems necessary based on the length of the cell contents.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: What is your point? The widths set using my code above are exactly the ones I have commented in the code.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. You can set a width for a column, but if the text takes up more space, Word can render the table with a larger column. You can read about setting table and cell widths in the spec at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm POI uses the first edition spec. Part 4 has a rigorous description of how table layouts work. It calls width `preferred width` as the layout engine uses that as one component of multiple factors in deciding the displayed width of a cell.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Take my code and replace the line `tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("CLientID");` with `tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("CLientID lorem ipsum semit dolor lorem ipsum semit dolor lorem ipsum semit dolor lorem ipsum semit dolor lorem ipsum semit dolor lorem ipsum semit dolor");`. Word will then increasing the row height but not the column width. Of course my code sets the column widths only for row 1. You must set it for all cells in all rows to make it absolutely fix.

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong. But notice that you have explicitly assigned the table width, and all cell widths. The cell widths in the rows all add up to the table width. And the table grid is defined with column widths that match the cell widths in all the rows. That makes the table appear fixed even though it is using the auto-fit layout. Folks just have to be careful. You can't just pick a different cell width on one of the cells and have it used. Folks have tried, and it results in questions.