# Internal cttable grid null using apache poi

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

We are using poi to render into a word document and then convert to pdf.  The PDF converter is failing - and when I debugged into it - what I found is that it's using calling the internal bean functions and the "tblGrid" - which it's using the apache XWPFTableUtil to call computeColWidths to work out the table size, and that throws a null reference exception because getTblGrid returns null.

Basically the code to reproduce it is easy:

```
output = new XWPFDocument( {stream to template} );
XWPFTable table = output.createTable();
Ensure.notNull( table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid() )
```

now - obviously I can't easily change the pdf library - so what I want is to figure out how to make that call not return null - it looks like there should be a function "calculategrid" or something?  I've searched, but can't find anything.

Anyone know what I'm missing?   (Btw it happens if I add rows and columns to the table, it's not as simple as the fact that it's just empty - I'm just using this as the simplest possible example).

Comment: `apache poi` does not using table grid in its current implementations. Instead it relies on `Word` to render the table automatically dependent on the cell contents while opening the document. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251975/how-to-increase-width-of-column-of-table-in-word-file-by-java/42254536#42254536 I have shown how to set column widths programmatically using `apache poi`. There is also `CTTblGrid` involved.

Comment: thanks - will give it a go!

Comment: @AxelRichter This is the correct answer.